# Поэлементный вывод QByteArray c записью в QString

Tags: c++, массивы, qt, строки

Есть массив `QByteArray RecData` из 8 элементов. **Мне нужно вывести его элементы через `"-"` последовательно, записав их в одну строку**. Я пробовал что-то вроде:

```
QString StringRecData;
for (int i; i < 8; i++)
{
   StringRecData += RecData[i];
   if ( i!=7 )
      StringRecData += '-';
}
```

Однако ничего в `QString`, кроме черточек не записывается. Всю строку целиком я переводил через `RecData.toHex()`, а поэлементно использовать `toHex` не получается. Можете подсказать какие-нибудь не очень сложные способы вывода через разделитель?

Comment: > Всю строку целиком я переводил через RecData.toHex(), а поэлементно использовать toHex не получается. Привидите пожалуйста код.

Comment: Результат toHex можно записать в QString и оттуда забрать поэлементно

Comment: @Unick 
QString StringRecData = RecData.toHex();
просто напрямую оно сплошняком записывало данные. Если в массиве были числа 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x5f 0x81 оно выводило их в виде 010203045f81, а мне нужно чтобы они выводились 01-02-03-04-5f-81

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему более простым способом:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    if (i != 7)
    {
        StringRecData += QString("%1-").arg((unsigned char)RecData[i], 2, 16, QChar('0')); //0, 16
    }
    else
    {
        StringRecData += QString("%1").arg((unsigned char)RecData[i], 2, 16, QChar('0'));
    }
}
```

Всем спасибо за ответы и наводки.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй использоваться QTextCodec для конвертации

QString DataAsString = QTextCodec::codecForMib(1015)->toUnicode(RecData);

(1015 is UTF-16, 1014 UTF-16LE, 1013 UTF-16BE, 106 UTF-8)

Вот тут уже разбирался этот вопрос(на англ)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131127/qbytearray-to-qstring

Answer (score 1):

Убери проверку на if она там не нужна:

```
if ( i!=7 );
```

Если необходимо поэлементно подсчитывать попробуй использовать это:

```
QByteArray arr;
arr.resize(3);
arr[0] = 6;
arr[1] = 7;
arr[2] = 8;
qDebug() << hexString(arr); // "06 07 08"
```

Предварительно узнав размер каждого элемента массива. Далее что бы корректно преобразовать все тебе так же необходимо разобраться с этим:

```
bool ok;
QString str; str.append(QString::number(RecData[0]));
int dec = str.toInt(&ok, 16);
qDebug() << "dec "<< dec;
```

это позволит тебе преобразовывать QByteArray в необходимый числовой тип(dec, hex, bin, etc).